# What is the expected minimum of Uniform (1, theta)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ be iid from Uniform$[1, \theta]$ with $\theta>1$ and the pdf of $X$,

$$
f_X(X=x)=\frac{1}{\theta - 1}, 1 < x < \theta
$$

Let $Y = \min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$. Find $E[Y]$

This is my answer:

$$
F_{X}(x) = \int_1^x\frac{1}{\theta - 1}dx = \frac{x-1}{\theta-1}
$$

PDF of $Y$:

$$
f_{Y}(x) = n(1-F(x))^{n-1}f(x)= n\frac{(\theta - x)^{n-1}}{\theta-1}\frac{1}{\theta - 1} = \frac{n}{(\theta-1)^n}(\theta - x)^{n-1}
$$

$$
E(Y)=\int_1^{\theta}y \frac{n}{(\theta-1)^n}(\theta-y)^{n-1}dy
$$

I am stuck here, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y = \min(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$,

$$
F_{Y}(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P(\min(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \leq y) \\
F_{Y}(y) = P(X_1 \leq y, X_2 \leq y, ..., X_n \leq y) \\
F_{Y}(y) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i \leq y) = [F_X(y)]^{n} = \left(\frac{y-1}{\theta - 1}\right)^n \\
f_Y(y) = n \left(\frac{y-1}{\theta - 1}\right)^{n-1} \times \frac{1}{\theta - 1} \\
\\
$$

Now compute the expected value,
$$
E[Y] = \int_1^{\theta} \frac{ny}{\theta - 1} \left(\frac{y-1}{\theta - 1}\right)^{n-1} dy
$$
Substitute $t = y-1$,
$$
E[Y] = \int_0^{\theta-1} \frac{n(t+1)}{\theta - 1} \left(\frac{t}{\theta - 1}\right)^{n-1} dt \\
E[Y] = \frac{n}{(\theta-1)^{n}}\int_0^{\theta-1} (t+1)t^{n-1} dt \\
E[Y] = \frac{n}{(\theta-1)^{n}}\int_0^{\theta-1} t^n + t^{n-1} dt \\
E[Y] = \frac{n\theta + 1}{n+1}
$$

You essentially missed integration by substitution.

Comment: Thank you! Shiv